# Grab firsts distinct entities ordered by datetime using Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

What I have

**Message Entity**

```
user  | text                          | date 
---------------------------------------------- 
user1 | This is first message user 1  | 10:50     **
user2 | This is first message user 2  | 10:50     **
user3 | This is first message user 3  | 10:50     **
user1 | This is second message user 1 | 10:00
user4 | This is first message user 4  | 10:00     **
user2 | This is second message user 2 | 10:00
user3 | This is second message user 3 | 10:00
user1 | This is third message user 1  | 9:00
...
```

With that data I want to grab the first message of each distinct user using CoreData in a single fetch request.

That is

```
user1|This is the first message user 1|10:50
user2|This is the first message user 2|10:50
user3|This is the first message user 3|10:50
user4|This is the first message user 4|10:00
```

You can achieve that by grabbing first the distinct users, and then, perform a fetch request for each user using a predicate, but it will end with a lot of "queries" (5 in this case). It would be nice if it can be done in a single request.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a relationship to your user entity called something like 'lastMessage' which you will always keep up-to-date whenever you insert a new message. Then the problem becomes trivial.

In my experience it's easier to de-normalize your schema slightly to improve performance rather than trying to create really complex queries.

EDIT to show entities:

```
------------- 1  R1     * ------------
|User Entity|<----------->| Message  |
-------------             ------------
| name      |------------>| text     |
-------------    R2     1 | date     |
                          ------------
```

You have two entities - User and Message. Set up 2 relationships between the entities:

R1 - 'messages' bidirectional one-to-many (one user has many messages and one message belongs to one user)

R2 - 'lastMessage' unidirectional one-to-one (one user has one last message)

Keep R2 up-to-date whenever you add a new message.

To get last messages for all users perform a fetch request for all users and then just look at the R2 relationship.

Use setPropertiesToFetch: on the NSFetchRequest to populate the R2 relationship in a single trip to the database.

Comment: On re-reading your question, I'm not sure you *do* have a User entity. If not, create one and keep track of distinct users and their last messages.

Comment: I don't see your point. That relationship will be in each user "row", won't it? I would need to update that property of each user with each update

Comment: Actually I don't have a user entity. Supposing I have a user entity with a relationship to Messages Entity, first i will grab all entities of User type, and the all the relationships will be "faulted", making a new query for each one. Am i right?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the entities and relationships. Shame you can't draw proper diagrams in SO!

Comment: First of all, thanks for that elaborate answer!! Do you know if "includeSubentities" will load all Messages for each user? At the end, each user has a relationship one-to-many with messages

Comment: Sorry - I'm getting confused about what includeSubentities does. Hold on for a second!

Comment: setPropertiesToFetch: is what you want. Just specify 'lastMessage' to load the last message relationship and not populate all the messages.

Comment: I think the method for prefetching the relations is setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way.  Do a fetch request of the user fields.  This will produce a set containing each distinct user.

Next, enumerate through the set:

```
for (NSManagedObject *obj in fetchController.fetchedObjects){

}
```

Inside this loop, you can do another fetch using the obj object for the predicate.  Sort by date wiht a maximum return of 1.  The resulting set will be one object which is the first message for that user.

Comment: That is what I'm doing right now, but it has the problem of growing requests. For 10 distinct users you have 11 requests. Think you have 100 different users.